# CMakeLists.txt: (add_executable): No SOURCES given to target: Tutorial

Tags: c++, cmake

While going through the [CMake Tutorials Page](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/index.html) and on Step 1, I saved the CMakeLists.txt file with the following lines of code:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

# set the project name and version
project(Tutorial VERSION 1.0)

# add the executable
add_executable(Tutorial tutorial.cxx)
```

Running this generates an error stating that the tutorial.cxx is not found.

I do not have the tutorial.cxx but the tutorial itself does not have any description where to get started or how to create the tutorial.cxx file. How can I find the Help/guide/tutorial directory that is described in the tutorial text?

Comment: Not sure this fits on SO, but from reading the link you sent, you should have created those files as part of Step1.

Comment: Hi Kai, thanks for your response.  Step1 shows code for the CMakeLists.txt file and alludes to the existence of a .cxx file that computes the square root of a number but it's not clear to me where that file is.

Comment: Fix for this issue is, name of the file on filesystem and the cmakelists.txt has to be the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The introduction on the same [page](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/index.html#cmake-tutorial) describes where the code is located within the CMake source code repository (see bolded section below):

> The CMake tutorial provides a step-by-step guide that covers common build system issues that CMake helps address. Seeing how various topics all work together in an example project can be very helpful. **The tutorial documentation and source code for examples can be found in the `Help/guide/tutorial` directory of the CMake source code tree.** Each step has its own subdirectory containing code that may be used as a starting point. The tutorial examples are progressive so that each step provides the complete solution for the previous step.

Where can you find the CMake source code? Look here:

- [GitHub](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake)
- [CMake Downloads Page (Source Distributions)](https://cmake.org/download/)